# abc= prove: $3+2(ab+bc+ca)\ge\sqrt{1+4(a+b)}+\sqrt{1+4(b+c)}+\sqrt{1+4(c+a)}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0: abc=1.$ Prove that: $$3+2(ab+bc+ca)\ge\sqrt{1+4(a+b)}+\sqrt{1+4(b+c)}+\sqrt{1+4(c+a)}$$

My try to prove stronger one:  Let $a,b,c>0: abc=1.$ Prove that: $$3+2(ab+bc+ca)\ge\sqrt{3(3+8(a+b+c))}$$ which is false.
Also, I denoted $(a,b,c)=(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x})$ but the rest seems complicated.

I hope someone can help me a hint to solve this hard problem. Thanks!

*Remark.* It've been here for a long time. Is the following stronger inequality true?
$$3+2(ab+bc+ca)\ge\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{3+8(a+b+c)}.$$

Comment: Interestingly, the inequality still holds with $a^2+b^2+c^2$ instead of $3$ ([Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+of+a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%2B+2%28ab%2Bbc%2Bca%29+-sqrt%281%2B4%28a%2Bb%29%29-sqrt%281%2B4%28c%2Bb%29%29-sqrt%281%2B4%28c%2Ba%29%29%2C+abc%3D1)). Unfortunately, you need to prove the inequality for a smaller LHS so this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the problem is stronger than a^2+b^2+c^2

Comment: Actually, the stronger inequality still holds.

Comment: What is stronger one ?

Comment: @TobyMak $ (a+b+c)^2 \geq 3 + 2(ab+bc+ca) \geq \sum \sqrt{ 1+ 4(a+b) }$. Your inequality is weaker than OP's.

Comment: What is OP? My problem is stronger

Comment: @Mars, OP means “original poster” or “original post”. It means you or this question here.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I got it. Is there any hint for me? It seems nightmare to prove it. The problem is nice but I don't see any idea to solve it.

Comment: I should have said that $3+2(ab+bc+ca)\ge\sqrt{3(3+8(a+b+c))}$ is true.

Comment: @TobyMak, that is false. For example, $a=100$, $b=c=1/10$.

Comment: @TobyMak, did you say "$3+2(ab+bc+ca)\ge\sqrt{3(3+8(a+b+c))}$ is true"? I meant that inequality is not true.

Comment: Woops, I typed the wrong thing so you're right.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof.**

By using AM-GM \begin{align*}
     \sqrt{1+4(b+c)}&= 2\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+abc(b+c)}\\&\le \frac{\dfrac{1}{4}+abc(b+c)}{bc+\dfrac{1}{2}}+bc+\dfrac{1}{2}\\&=\frac{\dfrac{1}{4}+abc(b+c)}{bc+\dfrac{1}{2}}+bc-\dfrac{1}{2}+1\\&=\frac{bc(bc+ca+ab)}{bc+\dfrac{1}{2}}+1\\&=2(ab+bc+ca)\cdot\frac{1}{a+2}+1.
\end{align*}
Thus, it is sufficient to prove $$\frac{1}{a+2}+\frac{1}{b+2}+\frac{1}{c+2}\le 1$$
$$\iff \frac{ab+bc+ca+4(a+b+c)+12}{abc+2(ab+bc+ca)+4(a+b+c)+8}\le 1$$
$$\iff ab+bc+ca\ge 3, $$which is obvious.

Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=c=1.$

Comment: Very elegant proof! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sickness why do you not accept it ?